# When running my Angular 13 and .Net Api project on the tablet, it does not enter a request to the api

Tags: .net, angular, asp.net-core

I have a project that I have developed with `Angular 13` and `.Net`.

So far I run this project successfully on the computer via `ng serve --host <my_ipadress>`, but I want to run it locally on the tablet.

When I switch to the tablet and open the project, it does not send a request to the api side and

```
Error: Failed to read the 'responseXML' property from 'XMLHttpRequest':
```

The value is only accessible if the object's `responseType` is '''
or `document` (was 'text') gives this error.

Note: when I open the **same url from the computer, it does not cause problems to the api**.

What is the problem cause?

Comment: try `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0` (yes, 0.0.0.0!) and open then the url (ip of your pc) from the tablet, like: 192.168.0.1:4200.

Comment: I tried this method but unfortunately it didn't work, this time it didn't send any requests to the api

Comment: Only the api communication? Then it looks like a api issue.. But you show us no code. We need the http request in the frontend and the backend code.

Comment: Actually, I don't think there is an api problem because when I enter the same address from the windows computer, ie 192.168.1.25:4200, it works smoothly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want access the application on the same LAN. We should make sure the frontend and backend application can be accessed. The sample url could be like below:

Angular Application can be reached via the url below.

```
http://192.168.1.20:4200
```

Api Application can be reached via the url below.

```
https://192.168.1.20:44375
```

---

Excute the command below,

```
netsh http add iplisten ipaddress 192.168.1.20
```

Then we can connect to web application from another machine on the same LAN.

Comment: The IP address was successfully added, but this time it broke on both the computer and the tablet :) –

Comment: Hi @ErenAkgöz We can talk about this issue in this thread. Thanks

Comment: @ErenAkgöz Ok, can you try to use another PC and try to access `http://192.168.1.20:4200`. Is everything OK ?

Comment: :) you are right. `"netsh http add iplisten ipaddress 192.168.1.20` unfortunately didn't work, do you have a different suggestion?

Comment: "netsh http deleteiplisten ipaddress 192.168.1.20" removed the ip address listening and the computer was fixed

Comment: @ErenAkgöz I know it from your previous post, could you tell me how about accessing the http://192.168.1.20:4200 site in another PC in the same LAN. It's important for me.

Comment: @ErenAkgöz The command `netsh http add iplisten ipaddress 192.168.1.20` you should excute it and share me the latest error. By the way we should create [New Inbound Rule](https://kb.diadem.in/how-to-configure-iis-to-access-website-using-ip-address_1080.html) .

Comment: @ErenAkgöz What is the (api) server side ip ? Same as the angular web app ?

Comment: this is the last error: https://ibb.co/Vtqcvn9

my server side is .NET and my apim is as follows https://localhost:44375/WebAPI/api/Auth/login

Comment: @ErenAkgöz I found the reason, let me explain to you.

Comment: @ErenAkgöz You are running the two application in one machine, right ?

Comment: Yeah, what's the reason? I'd be happy to explain.

Comment: @ErenAkgöz Why you can run it normally in PC, because when you access the site, it knows the localhost:44375. And tablet don't know what is localhost.

Comment: @ErenAkgöz Now the behavior is the angular frontend has sent the request successfully, but can reach to the server side. The solution is we should change the api url to https://192.168.1.20:44375. Make sure it can be reached  on the same LAN.

Comment: Is there a solution to this?

Comment: @ErenAkgöz I am still waiting for your update, this issue has been bothering you for nearly a month. I am here, no worries.

Comment: :) I can now send requests via tablet Thanks. I'm grateful to you

Comment: @ErenAkgöz I have updated my answer, if my answer useful to you, could you accept it as answer. Thanks