# Angular Capacitor App to connect .net core api in local machine

Tags: android, angular, asp.net-core, capacitor

I have created an angular app with capacitor and it needs to talk to .net core(6.0) api running in my local(http://localhost:5103).

What i tried:

Updated launchSettings.json to open api with local IP address.

```
"my.web.app": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "dotnetRunMessages": true,
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "applicationUrl": "http://192.168.x.x:5103",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
}
```

Now my api is running on http://192.168.x.x:5103

Now if i use this url to connect to api from android app, getting below error

> net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

FYI, here is my cors configuration to allow traffic from multiple ports

```
builder.Services.AddCors(corsBuilder => corsBuilder.AddPolicy("AllowSpecific", corsBuilderObj =>
{
    corsBuilderObj.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200", "http://localhost:4300", "http://localhost:8100", "http://localhost").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
}));
```

What am i missing?

- Is there any other way to access local api from capacitor angular app?

Comment: Hi Hakuna, could you share an update on this issue, I am willing to help you if you need.

Comment: Thanks @JasonPan. I've found the solution.

Answer (score 1):

After a long search I found solution myself. Capacitor defaultly accepting only http request from outside. In capacitor.config.json, androidScheme was set to https by default.I've made it **http**, then it started working.

```
> "server": {
>     "androidScheme": "https",
>     "cleartext": true,
>     "allowNavigation": [
>       "http://beplus-web-api-beta.eba-uw2jvq2f.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/*"
>     ]   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing, we can try to turn off the windows firewall. If it works, you need to add the new inbound rules to allow the specific port 5103.

If the firewall rules not works, then we can try to execute the command below to fix the issue.

```
netsh http add iplisten ipaddress 192.168.<your_ipv4_addr>
```

For more details, [you can check the thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77049784/7687666) , if there is any questions, please let me know.